# How do you fix the "validation failed: field "body" doesn't exist" error in azure-storage-blob-go?

Tags: go, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a multipart file to a blob with `AppendBlock()`, but I get this error:

```
-> github.com/Azure/azure-pipeline-go/pipeline.NewError, /home/makoto/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-pipeline-go@v0.2.1/pipeline/error.go:159
validation failed: parameter=body constraint=Null value=multipart.sectionReadCloser{SectionReader:(*io.SectionReader)(0xc000643a40)} details: field "body" doesn't exist
```

```
func Upload(file multipart.File) error {
    credential, err := azblob.NewSharedKeyCredential("credential strings", "")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    u, _ := url.Parse("blob url")
    appendBlobURL := azblob.NewAppendBlobURL(
        *u,
        azblob.NewPipeline(credential, azblob.PipelineOptions{}),
    )

    _, err = appendBlobURL.Create(
        context.Background(),
        azblob.BlobHTTPHeaders{},
        azblob.Metadata{},
        azblob.BlobAccessConditions{},
    )
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = appendBlobURL.AppendBlock(context.Background(), file, azblob.AppendBlobAccessConditions{}, nil)
    // validation failed: parameter=body constraint=Null value=multipart.sectionReadCloser{SectionReader:(*io.SectionReader)(0xc000643a40)}
    // details: field "body" doesn't exist
    return err
}
```

It works without raising an error if I pass a `string.Builder` instead of a multipart file.

Why do I get this error, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the dumbest errors I've encountered in Go, so this hopefully helps anyone running into this problem.

The error originates [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/blob/fc700035fe4a7020f50d49f420b3c088aed57e03/azblob/zz_generated_validation.go#L90). Right above this function, you can see that the value of `multipart.File` takes the `case reflect.Struct:` switch case. If you pass a `string.Builder` instead, it takes the `case reflect.Ptr:` path. We can force this path when we pass in a `multipart.File` by wrapping it in a struct and getting its pointer.

```
wrapper := &struct{ io.ReadSeeker }{file}
_, err = appendBlobURL.AppendBlock(context.Background(), wrapper, azblob.AppendBlobAccessConditions{}, nil)
return err
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `multipart.File` is indeed of type Struct when first retrieving a different form value using `r.FormFile("someKey")`, then calling `r.ParseMultipartForm()` and then using

```
type Block struct {
  File *multipart.File
  Name *string
}
func someFunction(r *http.Request, w http.ResonseWriter) error {
  r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, maxUploadSize)
  if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(maxMemory); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  someFunction1(r)
}
func someFunction1(r *http.Request) {
  var f multipart.File
  someFunction2(r, &f)

  name := "block1"
  b := Block{
    File: &f,
    Name: &name,
  }

  someUploadFunc(&b, "cn")
}
func someFunction2(r *http.Request, *v multipart.File) error {
  f := r.FormFile("fileKey")
  *v = f
  return nil
}
func someUploadFunc(b *Block, cn string) {
  curl := bs.NewContainerURL(cn)
  burl := curl.NewBlockBlobURL(*b.Name)
  lac := azblob.LeaseAccessConditions{}

  r, err := burl.StageBlock(ur.Context, "123", *b.File, lac, nil)
  ...
}
```

to reference a pointer to the file. In this scenario `*v` will be of type `Struct`. However, by changing the processing order to first calling `r.ParseMultipartForm()`, then `r.FormFile("someKey")` and then `r.FormFile("fileKey")`, `*v` is of type `multipart.File`.

It isn't quite clear to me why this is the case. Appears to be a Golang issue? Your solution indeed is a workaround, however as described above I was able to prevent the issue altogether by ensuring the order of my form processing is correct.

Comment: How did you declare `v`? I'm not able to follow your description. I want to point out that [the doc says](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile) "FormFile calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if necessary." I created this little test which works without connecting to Azure: https://gist.github.com/MakotoE/7fca93b2e89707015f4c5fe4bb8c7565.

Comment: That's great! I've updated my answer with some more code which is working for me. Sorry that I don't have the time right now to create a test for it. When you compose it in this way what is your result?

Comment: AppendBlock() takes an interface, not a pointer to an interface, so this doesn't work, unless I misunderstood something. I added a revision to the gist. I did change your code a bit since it results in nil pointer dereference.

Comment: I've elaborated my answer further, please note that I'm using `StageBlock()`, and the file is wrapped in a struct. I'm curious if this gives you different results.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the time you put into the answer, but I don't think you understand the problem. BlockBlobs don't have this problem; it's the AppendBlobURL, specifically the `AppendBlock()` method which exhibits this issue. Your answer doesn't compile, and even after fixing the syntax it results in nil pointer dereference. Therefore I can't accept this answer at its current state.

Comment: I did have the same issue that you described while leveraging `StageBlock`. Hence why I am trying to share my resolution for this `“validation failed: field ”body“ doesn't exist”` error so that other people that might save some time. But perhaps I received this error because of another cause. I'm not sure since it's pretty vague. I had also opened an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/issues/157#issuecomment-564293702